# Finding equations of two lines through $(0,0)$ tangent to $x^2-4x+y^2+3=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need to find equations of two lines that go through $(0,0)$ and tangent to the graph $$x^2-4x+y^2+3 = 0$$

So 
$$2x - 4 +2y\cdot y^\prime = 0 \qquad\rightarrow\qquad y^\prime = \frac{4-2x}{2y} $$

The equation of a line should be $y - y_0 = m(x-x_0)$, and $(0,0)$ should be a point on that line. So $y - 0 = m(x-0)$, where $m$ is the slope of the line, which I should just place the $y^\prime$ instead. Then I get 
$$y -0 = \frac{2-x}{y} (x-0) \qquad\rightarrow\qquad y = \frac{x(2-x)}{y}$$

But it is not the answer, as the answer is $$y = \pm \frac{3}{\sqrt{x}}$$

Comment: You also need to put $(x,y)=(0,0)$ to get value of tangent at $(0,0)$. Which is $2/0$ here

Comment: obviously $(0,0)$ does not belong to the curve. something is wrong.

Comment: it isn't . but it is belong to the line tangent to the curve so I tried to define the equation of the line tangent to the curve and the use $\ (0,0) $

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> (...) then I get $\ y -0 = \frac{2-x}{y} (x-0) \rightarrow y = \frac{x(2-x)}{y} $
>
> but it is not the answer as the answer (...)

It can't be the answer because the expression you write is not the equation of a line! The slope is a **number** so you still need to evaluate the expression you obtained for $y'$ via implicit differentiation. Where? Well precisely in the point(s) where it is tangent to the given equation, but you don't know where that is (yet)!

---

Alternatively: the equation of a line passing through the origin $(0,0)$ is of the form $y=mx$. Substituting into $x^2-4x+y^2+3 = 0$, you get a quadratic equation in $x$ with parameter $m$:
$$x^2-4x+(mx)^2+3 = 0 \iff \left(1+m^2\right)x-4x+3=0$$
The line "touches" the graph (i.e. it is **tangent**) if this equation has exactly **one** solution, so you want the discriminant $D=b^2-4ac$ to be $0$ which easily gets you the values for $m$, without the need for differentiation:
$$\underbrace{16-12(1+m^2)}_{D=b^2-4ac}=0 \iff  m = \pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$$
This is probably what you meant instead of:

> as the answer is $\ y = \pm  \frac{3}{\sqrt{x}} $

which isn't the equation of a line either.

Here's a [plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%7Bx%5E2-4x%2By%5E2%2B3%20%3D%200,y-x%2Fsqrt(3)%3D0,y%2Bx%2Fsqrt(3)%3D0%7D) to illustrate the result.

---

Addition after comment.

Look at the graph: an arbitrary line will usually either have no points of intersection with the circle (the corresponding equation in $x$ will then have $0$ solutions; strictly negative discriminant) or two points of intersection (the corresponding equation in $x$ will then have $2$ solutions; strictly positive discriminant).

In the (somewhat special) case of a tangent line, there is exactly **one** point of intersection (the corresponding equation in $x$ will then have $1$ solution; zero discriminant). Expressing this condition (on the discriminant of the quadratic equation in $x$) gives you **two** possible solutions for the parameter $m$ (not $x$!).

So you have two (different) cases with slopes $m$, corresponding to lines with exactly **one** point of intersection with the circle; so don't mix:

- you require the quadratic equation in $x$ to have **one** solution by setting the discriminant $0$;
- the equation for the discriminant being $0$ then yields **two** possible values for the slope $m$.

Comment: Why do you say the equation has exactly **one** solution? The equation should have two solutions as it says we are looking for **two** lines tangent to the curve that both passes through $\ (0,0) $

Comment: Too long to comment; I'll add it at the end of my answer.